# Quicksort incorrect results

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I have this quicksort code which I want to troubleshoot. There is this code that I have changed in the partition. Have tried selected the pivot element as the median of the array. But still it does not give me the correct output. Here I have different four types of arrays that I have created dynamically and trying to sort them. There are quicksort applied four times.

```
int counter=0, comparison=0;
void QUICKSORT(int *,int,int);
int PARTITION(int * ,int,int);
int values(float l);

int main(){

    int i,n,q;
    cout<<"Enter number of elements:";
    cin>>n;
    int* a = new int[ n ];
    for(int p=1;p<=n;p++)
    {
        q = rand() % (n*100) ;
        a[p]=q;
    }
    cout<<"\nThe elements od the original array are:\n\n";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    QUICKSORT(a,1,n);
    cout<<"\nThe elements of the sorted array are:\n\n";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";


}


// function for the generation of random poisson values. This function is called as many times
// as the array size decided by the user

int values(float l)
{

    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
    float L=exp(-l);
    float k=0;
    float p=1;
    //begin while
    do{
    k=k+1;
    double u = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    p=p*u;

    }   while (p>L);
    return k-1;
    }
}


//}
void QUICKSORT(int *a,int p,int r){
    int q;
    if(p<r){
        q=PARTITION(a,p,r);
        QUICKSORT(a,p,q-1);
        QUICKSORT(a,q+1,r);
    }
}
int PARTITION(int *a,int p,int r){
    counter++;
//    cout<<" first a " <<a[p]<<endl;
//    cout<<" second a : "<<a[r-1]<<endl;
    int x=(a[r]+a[p])/2;
    //int x=a[r];
    int i = p-1,temp,j;
    for(j=p;j<=r-1;j++){
        if(a[j]<=x){
            i=i+1;
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    temp=a[i+1];
    a[i+1]=a[r];
    a[r]=temp;
    return(i+1);
}
```

Comment: You write that "I have this quicksort code which I want to troubleshoot." -- what is preventing you from troubleshooting?  What have you done so far and what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Advice for troubleshooting: Cut down the code by as much as possible to find out where the error is occuring. If you post 5 lines of code here asking a question, you're far more likely to get a reply. If you post tons of code, only people desperate for rep (or people who are far too kind) will reply.

Comment: Also, don't dynamically create the data.  Use a known set of data that always causes the problem, and work with that until the problem is solved.  Having data change on you while you're solving a problem is a programmer's nightmare.

Comment: David : I have reduced the code.

Comment: Edward : If I have this int x=(a[r]+a[p])/2; , then it is not giving me the correct output but if I have this int x=a[r], it works fine. I wanted to change the pivot element selected and instead make median as the pivot element.

Comment: I see undefined behavior. Did you test *any* of these functions?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what a median is. Also what you have inaccurately remembered is the "median of three" method. Further, there is an inconsistency between your PARTIONing and your recursive call parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance..

```
QUICKSORT(a,p,q-1);
QUICKSORT(a,q+1,r);
```

That looks like it should be either:

```
QUICKSORT(a,p,q);
QUICKSORT(a,q+1,r);
```

or:

```
QUICKSORT(a,p,q-1);
QUICKSORT(a,q,r);
```

But also that partition method looks very questionable.  Even if it successfully finds the median I doubt it's worth the effort.  The point of quicksort is to sort with as few comparisons as possible, so looping through each entire subarray to find the median kind of defeats that purpose, and is overkill.  I would suggest picking three items: first, middle, last, and just using the median of those.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But when I am doing that with x=a[r]. It gives me correct output too. How is that possible?

Comment: Probably because your method of choosing the pivot only matters in the worst-case scenario, i.e. on almost-sorted data. That's why it's not worth finding the exact median.

Comment: To clarify: your choice of pivot doesn't change the sorted output, it only affects the speed of the algorithm.